# WriteXLSX gem not print date format properly print as normal number format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xlsx

Need to print date in xlsx file mm/dd/yyyy format, added the format using add_format method, but its printing as '2019-09-27 elabrated date

```
workbook = ::WriteXLSX.new(file, strings_to_urls: false)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet 1')
row=column=1
date_val = Date.today
date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'dd/mm/yy'})
worksheet.write(1 + row, column, date_val, date_format)
workbook.close
```

then i tried write_date_time method, code sample below

```
workbook = ::WriteXLSX.new(file, strings_to_urls: false)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet 1')
row=column=1
date_val = Date.today
date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'dd/mm/yy'})
worksheet.write_date_time(1 + row, column, item[:value]&.iso8601, date_format)
workbook.close
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with what you are doing is that you are passing a `date` object, but if you have read the [Date Time documentation](http://cxn03651.github.io/write_xlsx/dates_and_time.html#dates_and_time) then the first 2 lines says this -

> 1. A date/time in Excel is a real number plus an Excel number format.
> 2. WriteXLSX doesn’t automatically convert date/time strings in write() to an Excel date/time.

Now, to answer your question you need to convert the `date` to a `number` which the Excel understands.

`date_time = DateTime.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00.000Z')`

I have added `00:00:00.000` as you are not concerned with time if you want time also then check [strftime documentation](https://apidock.com/ruby/Time/strftime)

```
date_time_number = worksheet.convert_date_time(date_time)
format2 = workbook.add_format(:num_format => 'dd/mm/yy')
worksheet.write(row, col, number, format2)
```

This should solve it for you

[This helped me understand how to use convert_date_time](https://github.com/cxn03651/write_xlsx/blob/7d6dc2817acf4fb2ac25433a697af3f8e17f464f/test/worksheet/test_convert_date_time_04.rb) and its mention is at the bottom of the [Date Time documentation](http://cxn03651.github.io/write_xlsx/dates_and_time.html#dates_and_time)